# Redirect based on song start and current time

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I would like to redirect a page based on time remaining of a track. In one MySQL table I have the total song duration in milliseconds (like 208215) then also in that same table I have the start time of the track (like 2011-12-29 22:41:54...the time is central time by the way). Is there a way to make a redirect script that will redirect users when the track has finished?

Comment: I think we'll need more information. How is the track playing? Do you want PHP or JS to perform the redirection?

Comment: The track is playing on a streaming server, but the logs for what time the track aired and how long the track is are saved in a MySQL database.

Comment: If your using a JavaScript based player it should have some callback function when the song ends, you need to hook into that.

Comment: it's a continuous stream, so there is no way to tell when the track changes in the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'am getting it right you want a redirect after say .. 0:40 secs (the song length). If so, just do something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){setTimeout(){
window.location.href = 'redirect_url'
},40000}
```

After the page is loaded the function will count 40 secs and will redirect to the new url.